# CSS alignment DIV to new rule?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` container with two `div` elements inside it.
On the desktop version, the two `div` elements align next to each other.

On the mobile view I want them underneath each other. So I thought I just update the `min-width` to `100%` to force the next `div` to the next rule.

Well not really..... It's still next to each other, but the width of the screen just becomes twice as big.

```
<div class="blocks_container">
   <div class="block_content">
       Some content
   </div>
   <div class="block_content">
       Some content
   </div>
</div>

.blocks_container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 40px 0 40px 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.block_content {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 3% 2% 2% 0;
}
```

So I tried to change to `display: block` with a `float: left` but no luck.

I think this should be easily solvable, but, I couldn't solve it.....

Comment: first of all you missed closing div.

Comment: Point taken. This is only in the example here. Not in the real environment!

Comment: What do you mean "mobile view"? What browsers are you testing it? Have you set `meta viewport`? Is that really your HTML (since it is invalid)? http://sscce.org/ might be worth reading.

Comment: `flex-wrap` is probably what you need to investigate...

Comment: Why `min-width`? Why not just `width`? If it has a `width` of 100% then it will force the next div to the bottom.

Comment: Well. Mobile view... It's really in the name. A mobile device where a `@media` defines the css of that specific view width. As of now I'm testing on a iPhone 3, 4, and 5. The `meta viewport` is set: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` and Yes this is my HTML. This has changed like @ketan stated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all remove `display:flex` from `.blocks_container`

```
.blocks_container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 40px 0 40px 0;
    align-items: center;
}
```

And give fixed `width: 200px;` to `.block_content` because there is not more content in the div.

```
.block_content {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 3% 2% 2% 0;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6zfk1bm/1/)

To set div as per screen size suggest to use [media query](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Comment: I don't understand your question. May be I am wrong or you didn't explain your question correctly? @Interactive!

Answer (score 1):

use [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) queries to stack divs on smaller screens. They are easy to use and control.

```
.blocks_container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 40px 0 40px 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.block_content {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48%; //to compensate 2% right margin
    margin: 3% 2% 2% 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .block_content {
    width: 98%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the screen width you have to put a meta tag inside the head tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using flex you can specific `flex-direction`. So you could try this for mobile.

```
flex-direction: column;
```

And larger screens:

```
flex-direction: row ;
```